# Keyboard mapping, QWERTY INTL

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

i'm learning web development at the moment and we use an Oracle VM under Ubuntu.
I write quite a lot of French but i'm also a keyboard enthusiast which means i have a QWERTY board.
On my host OS (windows) i use the US International map which works great, it allows me to press ' + e and get é, etc.. So naturally i went the same route to setup my keyboard on Ubuntu.
It works, except that when i want to type just a ' or a ", i get  ´ and ¨ respectively.
If you know SQL, you know my pain at the moment.
I tried to fiddle around with the keyboard settings, tried 'sudo apt-get install console-common'. Nothing worked.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks for reading me.

Comment: In ubuntu you may need to install `GNOME Tweaks` and set the right windows key as your `compose` key in order to select special characters such as French accents.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point at two options:

1. Press <kbd>`</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> to type '
   Press <kbd>¨</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> to type "
2. Check out the *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)* keyboard layout. With that layout you use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>) to trigger the "dead key" behavior (to type accented characters). Otherwise you get e.g. ' or " directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try this out, once i get my VM back, it seems the console-common module i installed corrupted the system..